# Why my Loops won't execute?

Tags: c#, .net

Recently I have been asked to make an Array Sorter, However there is already built-in function for that, But I don't need it, I would like to know why the following script won't continue whenever it passes that comment line??

```
    int n;
    int t = 0;
    Console.Write("How many elements do you want to add? ");
    int length = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    int[] List = new int[length];
    while (t < length)
    {
        Console.Write("Enter {0} element value: ", t);
        n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        List[t] = n;
        ++t;
    }

    /////V The Below code is skipped for some reason V\\\\\

    int temp;
    int min = List[1];
    int min_i = 1;
    if (length < 2) { Console.WriteLine("Sorry, You can't sort a short    list!"); }
    else
    {
        for (int y = 1; y > length;)
        {
            for (int x = min_i - 1; x < 0; x--)
            {
                if (List[min_i] < List[x])
                {
                    temp = min;
                    List[min_i] = List[x];
                    List[x] = temp;
                }
                else break;
            }
            y++;
            min = List[y];
            min_i = y;
        }

    }
    for(int z = 0; z > length; z++)
    {
        Console.Write(List[z] + " ");
    }
```

Comment: `>` instead of `<` in last `for` loop, among other things.

Comment: If the code below the comment are skipped you probably are getting an exception in the code above the comments.  Are you entering all integers as inputs?

Comment: yes here is what I do input: http://prntscr.com/bcmpzd

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the rest (and adding to what others commented on) - this loop will always be false:

```
for (int y = 1; y > length;) // y = 1; length >= 2
```

Comment: why false? these is already an if statement above this loop that checks if the length > 2

Answer (score 0):

The condition defined for `for` loop is *always* false.

```
for (int x = min_i - 1; x < 0; x--) // x is zero and condition is false.
```

I guess, you have to change above line to

```
for (int x = min_i - 1; x > 0; x--)
```

Similar case with the top level loop as well, you might need to look for `y<length`

Comment: It didn't work, whenever I change it to y < length the app crashes. :/

Comment: Did you modify both the loops as mentioned in answer?

Comment: yes changed both, sometimes crashes sometimes skips.

Comment: @GhadeerAlali I got the reason, you should move `y++` increment to next line, that is causing an exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
int n;
        int t = 0;
        Console.Write("How many elements do you want to add? ");
        int length = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int[] List = new int[length];
        while (t < length)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter {0} element value: ", t);
            n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            List[t] = n;
            ++t;
        }

        /////V The Below code is skipped for some reason V\\\\\

        int temp;
        int min = List[1];
        int min_i = 1;
        if (length < 2) { Console.WriteLine("Sorry, You can't sort a short    list!"); }
        else
        {
            for (int y = 1; y <= length - 1; y++) //see #1 and #2
            {
                for (int x = min_i - 1; x >= 0; x--) //for loop was backwards see #2
                {
                    if (List[min_i] < List[x])
                    {
                        temp = min;
                        List[min_i] = List[x];
                        List[x] = temp;
                    }
                    else break;
                }
                //remove y++; and added to for loop
                min = List[y];
                min_i = y - 1;
            }

        }
        for (int z = 0; z <= length - 1; z++) //see #1 and #2
        {
            Console.Write(List[z] + " ");
        }
        Console.Read(); //added to prevent the program from closing until you press enter or manually close it
```

alright, so you're sorting code doesn't work. that still needs some problem solving. as far as your code goes....

1) so arrays start at 0 instead of 1. Your length doesn't. The code was breaking due to the length being 4, but the array only going to 3 ([0], [1], [2], [3]) so by adding the "length - 1", you don't change the length, but you can still reference it on the same number as the array, and it doesn't go outside the array.

2) You had pretty much all of your for statements backwards. Let me see if I can help you remember it a little better.

for (int a = 0;

this part just initializes the value

a <= 10;

think of this as a while statement. While (a <= 10) {Keep running the for loop}

a++)

and of course the increment.

If you'd like, I can help you with the sorting algorithm, as I've had to do a similar project when I was in school, cause right now it doesn't work like it should. Cheers!